# Speedometer crazy and transmission hard shifting 2004 Camry

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, speedometer

I have a 2004 Toyota Camry with 118k miles. Two weeks ago, my car began shifting rough and the speedometer needle began bouncing erratically. I brought it to a mechanic and the ECM was reporting a [p0500 code](https://repairpal.com/obd-ii-code-p0500).

So far, my mechanic has:

- Changed the transmission fluid and filter
- Replaced the vehicle speed sensor (VSS)
- Replaced the instrument cluster
- Checked wiring

Now the mechanic is considering replacing the ECM. I’ve suggested doing a hard reset on the ECM before that and I’m awaiting to hear if that helps.

Any ideas on what might be causing the hard shifting and the inaccurate speedometer readings?

Comment: I would take it to a qualified mechanic that can diagnose it correctly the first time, not throw parts at the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "shifting rough"?  Is it an Auto Transmission?

Comment: It is an auto transmission. It seems to shift hard when changing gears.